# What dialogue lines indicate the infected patient in Payday: The Heist?

Tags: payday-the-heist

In Payday: The Heist, the No Mercy mission requires you to identify an infected patient among three possible options.

According to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/78725/5398):

> ...each player gets a different dialogs from the doctor. For instance,
>   during our last game, I heard that patient A was bitten by a monkey,
>   but my friends heard that he came back sick from abroad.

It would be helpful to have a complete list of all of the phrases that indicate that a particular patient is the infected one, so that no matter what each player hears, they all know who the true target is.

**What are all the phrases that indicate that a particular patient is infected?**

Comment: I realize this is going to be a difficult question to answer.  Context: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5560815#5560815

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the guys I'm playing with and I, the only really revelant lines are those that are given during the second doctor's turn.  Listen to

1. the blood pressure (sometimes helping, sometimes not) but mostly
2. **when the patient will be able to come out of the hospital** (always a right indication so far).

You'll then have two main cases:

- If the patient's sickness has been identified/diagnosed and his treatment is going well, he'll be able to go back home soon, meaning it's not the guy your are looking for.
- If the doctor says she's not 100% sure what he suffers from and/or the guy has to stay for further examination and treatment, this is your guy.

To complete my previous answer, while playing multiplayer, different players will hear different things from the doctor; the estimate time before leaving the hospital is the only one that will point in the same direction for everyone (even if the information can be worded differently from one player to another).

Comment: I know you are more looking for a list of all possible lines, but in the meantime, I think this answer will do the trick ;)